# How can I get a XpsDocument in landscape within a DocumentViewer

Tags: wpf, printing

I'm trying to display an XpsDocument in a landscape mode but the Viewer always display it in portrait:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
memoryStream.Write(protectionInfo.Data, 0, protectionInfo.Data.Length);

XpsDocument xpsDocument = XpsHelper.CreateXpsDocument(memoryStream);

FixedDocumentSequence sequence = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

DocumentViewer viewer = new DocumentViewer();
viewer.Document = sequence;
Window window = new Window();
window.Content = viewer;
window.ShowDialog();
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I used a Word application to configure the document (Portrait/Landscape + PageSize), then export it to an XpsDocument. It works well by this way.

Comment: how are you creating the xps document? where are you serializing the flowdocument fixedapages to xpsdocument?

Comment: Is this gonna be used for printing using the PrintDialog class or through the built in of the DocumentViewer print?

Comment: The Xps document is created from a word document (.docx).
I need to print many things in the same job, the main idea of my printing process is to create one UserControl by page, put the UserControl into a FixedPage, add the FixedPage to a FixedDocument and then let the user print it through the DocumentViewer.